# useEffect se renderiza 2 veces

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, useeffect

Tengo un problema con el useEffect de react al momento de renderizar el componente se ejecuta dos veces

```
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Componente renderizado!!");
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h2>React</h2>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es intencional. El StrictMode de React renderiza dos veces los componentes para ayudarte a detectar efectos secundarios de la renderización. Esto solo ocurre durante el desarrollo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846289/why-is-my-react-component-is-rendering-twice

Comment: Gracias, justo eso estaba leyendo de la nueva version de react 18

Answer (score 4):

eliminar el `<React.StrictMode>` de index.js.

Como indica Federico Meza en los comentarios, el StrictMode de React renderiza ods veces los componentes (de forman intencional) para ayudarte a detectar efectos secundarios de la renderización. Sólo ocurre durante el desarrollo.